# The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.DateTime which is a non-nullable value type

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

```
var Ceremony = dc.GetOneCeremony(IdCeremony);
```

when run the top line show this error:

The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.DateTime which is a non-nullable value type.

Comment: Post the body of `GetOneCeremony`.  The problem is internal to that method, and without it, it's impossible to tell how to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

if you have a property Ceremony  class that has DateTime type change it to DateTime?
it seems GetOneCeremony returns an object that has null datetime field

Answer (score 0):

you're probably assigning a null value from a datareader to a datatime datatype.
something like:

```
DateTime dt = (DateTime)yourDataReader["YourDateTimeColumnWhichIsNull"].Value
```

Comment: Or consider using the GetValueOrDefault() method - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0.aspx